# Signin/up using google auth in Ruby app returning google console error

Tags: ruby

I  have a startup up and running using Devise for authentification, with an auth via Linkedin also working well.
I am looking to add the Google authentification using the `gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'`.
I build the controller's action and setup the model, but when trying the first call, i get:

```
I, [2021-04-05T09:38:21.376202 #53698]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2021-04-05T09:38:21.892030 #53698] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, {"code"=>403, "message"=>"Legacy People API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?projects=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.", "status"=>"PERMISSION_DENIED", "details"=>[{"@type"=>"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help", "links"=>[{"description"=>"Google developers console API activation", "url"=>"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?projects=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}]}, {"@type"=>"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason"=>"SERVICE_DISABLED", "domain"=>"googleapis.com", "metadata"=>{"service"=>"legacypeople.googleapis.com", "consumer"=>"projects/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}]}: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Legacy People API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?projects=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?projects=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "legacypeople.googleapis.com",
          "consumer": "projects/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I found multiple posts on internet but all the suggestions that I got did not work (mostly updating the gem with bundle update).
I also saw that we should be using Google People API instead. How can I make this happen please ?

Comment: The message says "go to this link and enable it, then wait a few minutes". Have you tried doing what the error message says?

Comment: Hi, yes yes, i tried it and got the error: There was an error while loading /apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXXXXX. Please try again.